# NGINX proxy forward with POST request gives 405 (Not Allow)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, rhel

I am making a post request from my frontend aplication, request to my node aplicaton running on server and listen for 4001 PORT.
Request look like : https://domain.name.com:4001/login - and wokrs fine.
I want to hide a port and make forwarding in NGINX so in my frontend aplication I can make request like https://domain.name.com/login.

I have try this NGINX configuration but it dont work, still gettin error 405(NotAllow):

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl default_server;

    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

 

    server_name domen.name.com;

 

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate/domain.crt;

    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificate/domain.key;

 

    root /mnt/storage/app/frontend/build;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

 

    location ~ ^/ {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

                                                     

    }


    location /login {

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4001/login;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;

        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_method POST;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }

}
```

addind : error_page 405 =200 $uri; - doesnot help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing might be related to the handling of the POST request method. By default, NGINX forwards the request method as-is, but some applications or APIs might not support direct forwarding of certain methods (e.g., `POST`) when performing proxying.

To fix this, you can try the following:

Instead of specifying the `proxy_method POST;`, remove this line. By default, NGINX will forward the original request method.

Add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Method $request_method;` inside the `/login` location block to set the `X-Forwarded-Method` header, which will keep track of the original request method.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    server_name domen.name.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certificate/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificate/domain.key;

    root /mnt/storage/app/frontend/build;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    location ~ ^/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /login {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4001/login;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Method $request_method; # Add this line
    }
}
```

After updating the configuration, don't forget to restart or reload the NGINX server to apply the changes:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick reply. Unfortunately, that has not solved error 405. Any other ideas?

Comment: ok, look like it works. Don't know why, but I had to delete a file from site-available and site-enabled, and run fresh file setup on server. 
After that I got 502 error Bad Gateway, which was caused by SELinux preventig connection on port 4001 for nginx process. 
solved by : 
"sudo cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep nginx | grep denied | audit2allow -M mynginx"
and
"sudo semodule -i mynginx.pp"

Comment: Confirm SELinux is always in the way! :)